# Pass Components to another component when not giving specified typescript types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Encountered a problem where I do not know how to work-around this in strongly typed variables.

So, I have a bunch of icons as components and an icon wrapper component.
Wrapper component has `themeMode` variable in order to determine in what color should icon be displayed. Hence, every icon needs `themeMode` variable, which is mandatory. However, I cannot think of the workaround when I have to pick an icon based of switch case scenario.

Here is the code for better understandment:
This component gets an id from a url and displays certain icon component.
However, every switch cases returning statements are underlined in red. That's because icon component NEEDS that `themeMode` variable. However, I'm giving it on iconWrapper component.

```
const CollectionEnd = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const getEndSvg = () => {
    switch (id) {
      case "bags":
        return <Bags />;
      case "shoes":
        return <Shoes />;
      case "men":
      case "women":
        return <Clothes />;
      case "hats":
        return <Hats />;
      default:
        return <Clothes />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <IconWrapper Component={getEndSvg()} />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Icon wrapper component:

```
const IconWrapper: React.FC<{
  Component: React.FC<{
    themeMode: string;
    style?: React.CSSProperties;
    isOpened?: boolean;
  }>;
  isOpened?: boolean;
  otherProps?: React.ReactNode;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
}> = ({ Component, style, isOpened, ...otherProps }) => {
  const themeMode = useAppSelector(selectThemeMode);
  return (
    <div style={style}>
      <Component {...otherProps} isOpened={isOpened} themeMode={themeMode} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is one of the icon component's emitted code:

```
const Bags: React.FC<{ themeMode: string }> = ({ themeMode }) => {
  return (
    <svg
      id='svg'
      xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
      width='200'
      height='200'
      viewBox='0, 0, 400,400'
      version='1.1'
    >
-----> ...emitedCode <------
```

Yes, I can simply make `themeMode` as not required, but that is not good. Also, I can wrap all switch case scenarios in IconWrapper. However, it looks repetitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach could be to change `IconWrapper` to accept `React.ElementType` and to pass the `Icon` component rather than an instantiated JSX.Element. This would let you delegate instantiating the `Icon` component to `IconWrapper`, which has the `themeMode` available.

In practice, this would look something like:

```
const CollectionEnd = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const getEndSvg = () => {
    switch (id) {
      case "bags":
        return Bags;
      case "shoes":
        return Shoes;
      case "men":
      case "women":
        return Clothes;
      case "hats":
        return Hats;
      default:
        return Clothes;
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <IconWrapper Component={getEndSvg()} />
    </Container>
  );
};

const IconWrapper: React.FC<{
  Component: React.ElementType<{
    themeMode: string;
    style?: React.CSSProperties;
    isOpened?: boolean;
  }>;
  isOpened?: boolean;
  otherProps?: React.ReactNode;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
}> = ({ Component, style, isOpened, ...otherProps }) => {
  const themeMode = useAppSelector(selectThemeMode);
  return (
    <div style={style}>
      <Component {...otherProps} isOpened={isOpened} themeMode={themeMode} />
    </div>
  );
};
```